# Hot questions widget - Refresh tap target too small

Tags: feature-request, android-app, hot-questions, android-app-widgets

The *Hot questions* widget that comes with the Android app has a refresh button with a tap target that is too small. It's just a small square box as seen here:

[image: current widget layout]

<sup>**Note:** The red/blue markings and pink shadings are from the *Developer option* called *"Show layout boundaries"*. They are not displayed on normal operation.</sup>

The problem with this is that I have to focus my fat finger on this box and hit it within the marked square. If I hit even slightly outside, the current question launches in the app.

And I kept launching questions several times when I didn't intend to.

It should really be something like this:

[image: proposed widget layout]

A big target in the right. So big, you can't miss it! `=)`

*Also, I'm not sure if this should be classified as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).*

<sup>Stack Exchange app v1.0.48

Android JB (4.3)

Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE (GT-I9305)

Stock ROM (rooted)</sup>

Comment: @StevenV I couldn't find it at all.. But hey, screenshots `:D`

Comment: I am a fan of the pictures, and thank you for putting the time in it to make a good bug report. However, the other one is slightly older and I don't really think the bug requires more understanding than "it's really hard to hit the button", so I'm closing this as a dupe of the older one.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Do closed duplicates get removed after a while? Otherwise I'm fine as long as the problem is getting fixed. This will help people finding this question get to the other one. Btw I'm curious how you fix this problem. Would be nice if you elaborated a little on the programming details in the other question's answer. (Feel free to use my shots.)

Comment: @ADTC Only if they are negatively voted and without answers. This one has +4 votes.